# Is equality reflexive for classes? (I.e. are instances always equal to themselves?)

Tags: c++, equality, compiler-optimization

In C++, testing for equality is typically implemented by each class individually. Under any reasonable implementation one would presumably expect an object to be equal to itself.

Do compilers make this optimisation?

In other words, if `&a == &b`, is a compiler allowed to assume that `a == b` for class types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Class types can only be compared with `==` if there is a suitable user-defined overload of the operator; and that overload can do anything at all, "reasonable" or otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

One counterexample is `NaN`. A `double` containing `NaN` does not compare equal to itself.

Comment: Although, a `double` is not a `class`.

Comment: That is true but as mentioned, double is not a class which I should have emphasised. I think you're right in that the answer is the same though.